# Flask grid edit using wtforms

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm working on a project that pulls a list of all the spirits listed in the Oregon State liquor pricing sheet and stores it in a table in my flask app. The goal is to be able to let moderators see the list and check a box next to each spirit to designate if it is whiskey or not.

It's my first time really using flask, but I've gone through a book about flask twice now to try and understand it, so this is me trying to build my own thing.

Right now, if I check a box and then hit submit all the records are switched to is_whiskey = False instead of each one being done individually.

Here's my model:

```
class Whiskies(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'whiskies'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ols_name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    display_name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    display_distiller = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=False)
    is_whiskey = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    reviews = db.relationship('Review', backref='review', lazy='dynamic')
```

Here's my view:

```
@main.route('/update-whiskies', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@permission_required(Permission.MODERATE)
def update_whiskies():
    whiskies = Whiskies.query.all()
    is_whiskey_form = IsWhiskeyForm()
    submitpageform = SubmitPageForm()
    if submitpageform.validate_on_submit():
        for w in whiskies:
            w.is_whiskey = is_whiskey_form.is_whiskey.data
            db.session.update(w)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("You updated a bunch of whiskies")
        return redirect(url_for('.index'))
    return render_template('update_whiskies.html', whiskies=whiskies,
                           is_whiskey_form=is_whiskey_form,
                           submitpageform=submitpageform)
```

Here's my .html page:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block page_content %}
<div>
    {% for whiskey in whiskies %}
    <li class="whiskey">
        {% if whiskey.display_name %}
            {{ whiskey.display_name }}
        {% else %}
            {{ whiskey.ols_name }}
        {% endif %}
        {{ is_whiskey_form.is_whiskey.label }}
        {{ is_whiskey_form.is_whiskey(value=whiskey.is_whiskey) }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
    {{ wtf.quick_form(submitpageform) }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here are my forms:

```
class IsWhiskeyForm(Form):
    "This is intended for use in bulk editing whiskies"
    is_whiskey = BooleanField("Is Whiskey", default="checked")


class SubmitPageForm(FlaskForm):
    "This is intended for submitting a batch edit"
    submit = SubmitField('Update Whiskies')
```

This is what the page currently looks like. I want to be able to check a box and hit submit and then have it reflected in the db.

[image: This is what the page currently looks like]

Thanks a lot to whoever is up to helping me with this. I've been stuck about a week and I just need to get past this hump to finish up my module.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar task to solve: producing a list of database records (1 record per row) and let the user choose one record. So I put a radiobox at the end of each row. The problem was how to inform the Flask app which row was checked. I came up with the following solution:

1. You must make the submit button of the form trigger a POST request
2. You need in the data you want to show in the browser one field which is unique so you can use it to identify a row (I had data from an SQL database to display, so the primary key of a record was a good solution)
3. Add a radiobutton in your html-template inside the `{% for ... %}` loop like this:

```
{% for data in dataset.items %}
    ... display the data of the row, plus:
    <div>
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input cursor-pointer" 
               name="check_line" value="{{ data._id }}">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

in the POST request data there will appear a name-value pair produced by the radiobuttons which consists of the name you provided (here: "check_line") and the value you provided. The trick is that the value can be used to identify the row (is unique) because the Flask-rendering-magic was used.

By the way: when testing POST-requests I often write:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request.values)
```

in the route-functions where POST needs to be handled. This will display all the POST input parameters on the Flask-console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if submitpageform.validate_on_submit():
    for w in whiskies:
        w.is_whiskey = is_whiskey_form.is_whiskey.data
    db.session.commit()
```

Remove db.session.update(w)

Comment: I updated after posting to have it use db.session.add(w) instead in order to update. It's a common way of doing it from what I can tell. Any reason I wouldn't want that line in there?

Comment: No, it didn't work. I tried it and the same issue occurs.